# dropdown menu slideToggle executing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do a dropdown menu, where if you have already one menu opened and click on the other menu, the first one will close. I am trying to do this with slideToggle + slideDown and slideUp.

It works, but the content of the menu is getting 'toggled' twice. And it transition is not so smooth as I thought it would be.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="section-four-wrap">
  <div class="section-two-text-fields">
    <div class="description-container container-1">
      <h3 class="h3-default">
        <b>Heading</b>
      </h3>
      <span class="text-placeholder">
        Text
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="description-container container-2">
      <h3 class="h3-default">
        <b>Heading</b>
      </h3>
      <span class="text-placeholder">
        value
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="description-container container-3">
      <h3 class="h3-default">
        <b>Heading</b>
      </h3>
      <span class="text-placeholder">
        value
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
.h3-default:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  width:100vw;
  height:1px;
  background:black;
}


.text-placeholder{
  display:none;
}


$(function () {

    $(".section-two-text-fields .description-container h3").click(function() {


        $(this).next().slideToggle();

        if($('.description-container .text-placeholder:visible').length > 1) {
            $('.description-container .text-placeholder:visible').slideUp();
            $(this).next().slideDown();
        }
    }); 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bg68jne1/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably do not need to check the length. First `slideUp()` all the visible elements then `slideToggle()` the next element. You can also pass value as milliseconds to the functions.

You can try the following way:

```js
$(function () {    
  $(".section-two-text-fields .description-container h3").click(function() {
    $('.description-container .text-placeholder:visible').slideUp(500);
    $(this).next().slideToggle(1000);
  }); 
});
```

```css
.h3-default:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  width:100vw;
  height:1px;
  background:black;
}


.text-placeholder{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section-four-wrap">
  <div class="section-two-text-fields">
    <div class="description-container container-1">
      <h3 class="h3-default">
        <b>Heading</b>
      </h3>
      <span class="text-placeholder">
        Text
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="description-container container-2">
      <h3 class="h3-default">
        <b>Heading</b>
      </h3>
      <span class="text-placeholder">
        value
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="description-container container-3">
      <h3 class="h3-default">
        <b>Heading</b>
      </h3>
      <span class="text-placeholder">
        value
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply, indeed it works now but still there are some weird displacements when clicking the elements which I am trying to find out why. I found exactly what I want to achieve its [here](https://www.gucci.com/au/en_au/pr/women/handbags/mini-bags-for-women/gucci-1955-horsebit-small-top-handle-bag-p-62122092TCG8563) basically the dropdown menu they have on the bottom left. Do you think that the code I have now is a way to achieve this?